# MySQL how to use check?

Tags: mysql

I am a very beginner in MYSQL and I am trying to use `CHECK` for `EmployeeID` is in the format of `E###` where "#" is the number(int). ANd the `DOB` that is eneterd should be 16 years or older from current date. Here is the code for the table. Thanks for help!

```
Create table Employee(
EmployeeID varchar(200) not null primary key,
DOB date, 

##Check (DOB <= CURRENT_DATE - interval '16' year),
FirstName varchar(200),
MiddleName varchar(200),
LastName varchar(200),
Address varchar(255),
StartDate date,
Gender varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: TimBiegeleisen it is 8.0.20

Comment: You _can't_ use a check constraint to check the date of birth column, you'll have to use a trigger.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to confirm the validity of the EmployeeID, such as this :-

`EmployeeID varchar(200) not null primary key CHECK EmployeeID REGEXP 'E\d{3}',`

Answer (score 0):

[Other answers covered using the check constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67238895/14660).

However, if it's *always* going to start with an 'E', do you need to store the 'E'? Can you store just the integer and add the E later? An integer primary key is simpler, faster, smaller, and more robust.

Use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to provide the ID with the E on it.

```
create table Employee (
  -- No check required, it's an integer by definition.
  -- Takes less storage to store and index.
  ID integer primary key,

  -- A generated virtual column (takes no storage space)
  EmployeeID varchar(255) as (concat('E', id)) virtual
);

insert into Employee (id) values (1), (23), (456);

select * from Employee;

ID      EmployeeID
1       E1
23      E23
456     E456

select * from Employee where EmployeeID = 'E456';

ID      EmployeeID
456     E456
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8d820c5731893b04e93c3e5beb95617).

Comment: What about the date of birth?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your answer is fine.